# Four icons added in the BottomNavigationBarItem is not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter I created a bottom navigation bar when I trying to add four icons. The icon color change to white. How should I achieve this can anyone suggest me. Below is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(items: [
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.add), title: new Text("Text")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person), title: new Text("Contact")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility), title: new Text("Acess")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance), title: new Text("Balance"))
  ]),
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When  you have more than 3 elements, you need to explicitly set `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,`

```
bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.add), title: new Text("Text")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person), title: new Text("Contact")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility), title: new Text("Acess")),
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance), title: new Text("Balance"))
  ]),
```

> When more than 3 BottomNavigationBar items are provided the type, if unspecified, changes to BottomNavigationBarType.shifting per https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/BottomNavigationBar.html.

Comment: Considering what you said above: How can you set the color of the active item from the 4 items? I've tried with fixedColor but is nor working.

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin I'm sure this was discussed here or in GitHub issues. If you can't find it, please create a new question. I don't know it by heart and I'm currently not working with Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `type` parameter under `BottomNavigationBar`:

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed
```

This would turn your four icons visible.